# Словарь не находит результат при использовании byte[]

Tags: c#

Написал обертку для словаря. Если объявлять его как `ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>` или `ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>` отрабатывает правильно. Но при `byte[]` не находит ключ.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace qwerty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();

            t.Set("type", "key", 4);

            Console.WriteLine(t.Contains("type", "key"));

            Console.WriteLine(t.FakeContains("type4", "key4"));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        private ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int>();

        public void Set(string type, string key, int value)
        {
            byte[] masterKey =
                Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(type.PadRight(64))
                .Concat(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key.PadRight(64)))
                .ToArray();

            cache.AddOrUpdate(masterKey, value, (k, v) => 5);
        }

        public bool Contains(string type, string key)
        {
            byte[] masterKey =
                Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(type.PadRight(64))
                .Concat(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key.PadRight(64)))
                .ToArray();

            return cache.ContainsKey(masterKey);
        }

        public bool FakeContains(string type, string key)
        {
            byte[] masterKey =
               Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(type.PadRight(64))
                   .Concat(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key.PadRight(64)))
                   .ToArray();

            byte[] fakeMasterKey =
               Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("type4".PadRight(64))
                   .Concat(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("key4".PadRight(64)))
                   .ToArray();

            cache.TryAdd(fakeMasterKey, 5);

            return cache.ContainsKey(fakeMasterKey); // True
            //return cache.ContainsKey(masterKey);     // False
        }
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

```
`False`
`True`
```

Ожидалось:

```
`True`
`True`
```

Comment: массив это ссылка, поэтому если вы создаете его - то ссылка другая и соответственно ключ другой, поэтому не находит ничего

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что хэшкод у каждого нового массива будет разный, даже если эти массивы имеют одинаковое содержимое.

Рекомендую к прочтению:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/245727/

Answer (score 6):

В качестве альтернативного решения при создании словаря можно использовать перегрузку конструктора принимающую `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Для этого нужно создать класс имплементирующий данный интерфейс, например так

```
public class ByteArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{

    public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

И далее использовать экземпляр этого класса при создании словаря:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int> cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<byte[], int>(new ByteArrayEqualityComparer());
```