# Почему не находит ключ?

Tags: c#

Добавляю новую пару в словарь.

```
private static void InitABC()
    {
        Area character = new Area("0001000\r\n0010100\r\n0010100\r\n0111110\r\n0100010\r\n1000001\r\n1000001");
        ABC.Add(character,'А');
    }
```

Обращаюсь по точно такому же ключу, но выдает ошибку о том, что такого ключа нет.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitABC();

            Area hh = new Area("0001000\r\n0010100\r\n0010100\r\n0111110\r\n0100010\r\n1000001\r\n1000001");

            char lh;
            lh = ABC[hh];

            Console.WriteLine(lh);
        }
```

Думаю проблема в том, что `Area`являтся ссылочным типом и тогда в качестве ключа передается адрес, а не значение. Соответсвенно при получении значения по ключу также передается ссылка, в которой записан другой адрес. Если это так, то как это можно исправить?

Comment: Зависит от реализации класса `Area` - вы переопределили в нем методы `Equals` и `GetHashCode`? Как по вашему словарь догадается, что 2 разных ссылочных объекта указывают на один и тот же ключ?

Comment: @Grundy что то не похоже на тот вопрос по ссылке

Comment: @tym32167, если рассматривать Area как составной ключ - то похоже. Плюс там ответы, которые и позволяют использовать в качестве ключа класс, либо подсказывают что использовать вместо этого

Comment: @tym32167, вот более похожий и более узкий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527797/186999)

Comment: @Grundy `Area` принимает только строку, какой составной ключ вы имеете ввиду? Хотя вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619605/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B2-dictionary/686671#686671) да, похож на то, что надо автору

Comment: @tym32167, мы не знаем что входит в Area, возможно у него есть куча публичных свойств заполняемых в конструкторе и проверять нужно по нескольким из них.  Поэтому то, что в конструктор передается одна строка ничего не показывает.

Comment: @Grundy `возможно у него есть куча публичных свойств` возможно есть, возможно нет - это уже чисто предположения. Но я понял, что вы имели ввиду